# span word wrap in ng repeat into new line

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have values in using ng repeat in span.I got word like in new line like

Actual output:

[image]

I used CSS like

```
    border: 1px solid #ECE9E6;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 33px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
```

I want output like:

[image]

Comment: What is the `display` value? If doubt if word break will work if its `inline-block`. Normally the word-break happens for block element which fits the whole screen and the there are loads of words forming many statements.

Comment: Try changing the `word-wrap` property to `nowrap`.

Comment: @ Vijay I am using display:block But if i use inline-block it works but then I have do more changes in CSS it will reflect other UI. Any other solution rather than inline-block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `word-wrap`over `span`. I'll suggest you to use `display:inline-block` in the parent div.

This will make sure your complete inner div will move to next line.

Answer (score 0):

Just make your HTML as below

```
<div id='mainDiv'>
<span class='tag'>abc</span>
<span class='tag'>lmn</span>
<span class='tag'>xyz</span>
<span class='tag'>etc</span>
<span class='tag'>etc</span>
</div>
```

Add css as below.

```
#mainDiv{
 width: 200px; // any pixel you want to set;
}
.tag{
display:inline-block;
}
```